# A better way to properly implement string 'in' array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, inclusion

suppose you have an array with a number of strings in ActionScript3 and you want to test if a test string is "in" that array. "in" only works against the index with Arrays in AS3 (which is totally retardo if you ask me), though it does work with ojects, but we're not talking about objects.

Can someone improve (reduce) on this code I'm using now? I'm hoping to avoid defining a utility function - I'd like a nice elegant one-liner.

```
myArray.filter(function(item:*, i:int, a:Array) { return (item == testString); }).length
```

Since 0 == false we can use it in a test. Do note that testString's scope is defined in the containing function, encapsulated by the closure.

```
if (allowedProfiles.filter(function(item:*, i:int, a:Array) { return (item == name); }).length){ // yay! }
```

Comment: You have 500 rep and don't know how to properly format code in a question. Think about it for a moment.

Comment: @Tomalak. Point taken. I was rushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Array.indexOf()` method to see that the index of the string in the array is not `-1` (not found):

```
var myArray:Array = ["hello", "world"];
trace(myArray.indexOf("hello")); // == 0;
trace(myArray.indexOf("goodbye")); // == -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [indexOf()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29)?

```
if(myArray.indexOf("testString") != -1) { // it's in there
```